# Compiling Unity3d for IOS error

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, mono

I use mono. Compiling for Android works well. But for IOS returns an error. Full error text:

> Cross compilation job Assembly-CSharp.dll failed.
>   UnityEngine.UnityException: Failed AOT cross compiler:
>   /Applications/Unity/Unity.app/Contents/PlaybackEngines/iOSSupport/Tools/OSX/mono-xcompiler
>   --aot=full,asmonly,nodebug,static,outfile="Assembly-CSharp.dll.s" "Assembly-CSharp.dll"  current dir :
>   /Users/hexgrim/Documents/BottleRepository/Bottle_Unity_IPad/Temp/StagingArea/Data/Managed
>   Env: Apple_PubSub_Socket_Render = '/tmp/launch-CZPXth/Render' LOGNAME
>   = 'hexgrim'
>   __CHECKFIX1436934 = '1' MONO_PATH = '/Users/hexgrim/Documents/BottleRepository/Bottle_Unity_IPad/Temp/StagingArea/Data/Managed'
>   TMPDIR = '/var/folders/fw/3hkfvy7j49xgk_tfq7kxx3ym0000gn/T/' PWD =
>   '/Users/hexgrim/Documents/BottleRepository/Bottle_Unity' SSH_AUTH_SOCK
>   = '/tmp/launch-okPdG6/Listeners'
>   _ = '/Applications/Unity/Unity.app/Contents/MacOS/Unity' GC_DONT_GC = 'yes please'
>   __CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING = '0x1F5:0:0' SHELL = '/bin/bash' GAC_PATH = '/Users/hexgrim/Documents/BottleRepository/Bottle_Unity_IPad/Temp/StagingArea/Data/Managed'
>   USER = 'hexgrim' HOME = '/Users/hexgrim' PATH =
>   '/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin' SHLVL = '2'  result file exists:
>   False. Timed out: False stdout: Mono Ahead of Time compiler -
>   compiling assembly
>   /Users/hexgrim/Documents/BottleRepository/Bottle_Unity_IPad/Temp/StagingArea/Data/Managed/Assembly-CSharp.dll*
>   Assertion at mini-arm.c:4771, condition `cfg->code_len <
>   cfg->code_size' not met stderr:
>
> at UnityEditor.MonoProcessUtility.RunMonoProcess
>   (System.Diagnostics.Process process, System.String name, System.String
>   resultingFile) [0x00000] in :0    at
>   UnityEditor.MonoCrossCompile.CrossCompileAOT (BuildTarget target,
>   System.String crossCompilerAbsolutePath, System.String
>   assembliesAbsoluteDirectory, CrossCompileOptions crossCompileOptions,
>   System.String input, System.String output, System.String
>   additionalOptions) [0x00000] in :0    at
>   UnityEditor.MonoCrossCompile+JobCompileAOT.ThreadPoolCallback
>   (System.Object threadContext) [0x00000] in :0 
>   UnityEditor.HostView:OnGUI()

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is an error in one .cs file. Just disable files one by one and try to compile.